# How should I set the duration of my MS program after converting from PhD?

Tags: masters, cv

I started my PhD program in CSE in Fall'16. Due to my personal and family issues, my professor agreed to convert my PhD to MS and let me graduate as early as possible in Spring, 2020. I have already finished all my course works for my MS during my PhD program. Only course that I have to take in Spring'20 is 6 hours thesis course. I converted my program from PhD to MS before Spring'20 began and will graduate in Spring'20.

Now at this stage, as I am also searching for job what should I say in my CV regarding my duration of MS completion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to mention anything about your path from PhD to MS. You can just put "Master's of Science, CSE, Institution Name" or however you deem fit to include into your CV.

It seems that when you're in academia, it is everything in life. You may have regrets about not completing a PhD, but you don't have to explain that all on your CV or even in a job interview because you'll still have the Master's.

The workplace stackexchange is a good place to look around for helping one prepare one's CV for job applications, interviews, and company culture. Good luck!